# How to get the page number of a Destination (in a GoToAction Annotation)

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose

I'm using Aspose PDF to examine a PDF that has been supplied to me. It contains internal hyperlinks (i.e. hyperlinks that take you to other pages within the document). For each hyperlink, I want to know the page number of the page it takes you to.

At the moment I'm looking at the Annotations property for each page: this gives me a list of hyperlinks on that page. I look at each one's Action. Where it is a GoToAction, I examine the Destination.

What I'm finding is that the Destination is a NamedDestination, for example with the Name "appendix-a".

What I want is the page number of the NamedDestination called "appendix-a". How can I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document(myDir + "test.pdf");
int pageNumber = pdfDocument.Destinations.GetPageNumber("appendix-a", false);
```

Note that the returned pageNumber is 1-based, not 0-based.

Answer (score 0):

I am working as Social Media Developer at Aspose. Check the following code segment to retrieve the page number information from a link on a page.

```
//open document
Document document = new Document("input.pdf");

//extract actions
Page page = document.Pages[1];
AnnotationSelector selector = new AnnotationSelector(new LinkAnnotation(page, Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle.Trivial));
page.Accept(selector);
IList list = selector.Selected;

foreach (LinkAnnotation annotation in list)
{

    int pagenum = ((Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.ExplicitDestination)(Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.FitExplicitDestination)(annotation.Destination)).PageNumber;
    Console.WriteLine("Page Number: " + pagenum);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to find the page number from a Destination that I retrieved from a Bookmark.  I had to use slightly modified code to that detailed above, as follows:  var bookmarkPageNo = ((Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.XYZExplicitDestination)(bookmark.Destination)).PageNumber;